# Minimizing the app, changing language and resuming calls onCreate() instead of onResume()

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I just noticed a weird issue I've been having in my app. When I'm running my app, if I minimize it, then go the settings and change the language, then resume my app(note: this is minimize/resume, not exit/start), it calls the Activity's `onCreate()` instead of calling `onResume()`.

This is causing a lot of issues, especially in areas where I'm using fragments in the view. The fragments being displayed are the old fragments, but the activity reference they are holding is `null`. So `getActivity()` doesn't work immediately after resuming, causing `NullPointerException` in many places.

My app is being built for Android 4.0.4 and above and I've noticed this issue on different devices and emulators, so it's not a platform issue.

Ideally, I'd like to call `onResume()` as it's supposed to. If not, I'd prefer to have the application relaunch itself silently and land the user on the home screen instead of having to face an App crash.

The app itself supports just one language: English(USA).

Has anyone faced this issue before? If yes, could you manage to resolve it?

EDIT: Based on Class Stacker's answer, It seems I need to handle the configuration change myself. Which should be fine, except that an exception is thrown in the `onCreate()` itself.  I am calling `getWindow().setRequestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)` in the `onCreate()`. When the locate changes, this line is throwing a `RuntimeException` saying that this must be called before `setContentView()`.

Does this mean my Activity is not getting destroyed properly?

Comment: Regarding your edit, to be sure: _Do_ you call `setRequestFeature()` before `setContentView()`?

Comment: Definitely. All my Activities inherit from a BaseActivity. The setRequestFeature is being called in the onCreate() of the base activity which is called in the onCreate() of my individual activities. It is only after that I call setContentView() in my activity.

Comment: Since my app only supports one language, I can "fix" it by setting configChanges="locale" in my Manifest, but I'd like to leave that as an absolute last resort.

Comment: Hmmm... and how are you handling your fragments across the config change now? Re-creating them?

Comment: You could still avoid the call to `setRequestFeature()` altogether upon detecting a config change, which is easy. Question is, does it yield the desired result.

Comment: I am not.. The thing is, the app only supports Portrait mode. So we weren't doing anything with the config changes. My fragment creating code comes after the onCreate().. So I am trying to see why the setRequestFeature() is throwing a RuntimeException in the first place..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25590/discussion-between-vinay-s-shenoy-and-class-stacker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an issue, it's by design.

If the language changes, that's a configuration change, just like screen rotation.

That means that quite a lot of things have to be re-created. Hence, this is handled via onCreate().

Sorry for the bad news but you'll have to correct the location where you create objects and how onCreate amnd onResume interoperate.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

**Edit:** Regarding the `RuntimeException`, to be on the safe side, call `getWindow().setRequestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, as you found out during our chat.

Comment: Hmm.. I see. The thing is, this won't be an issue. My Activity will recreate itself just fine. The problem is, the fragments living in the same activity don't seem to be destroyed, which is causing the issue. I'll try recreating them and see what happens.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy It might be necessary to store some data in a "nonconfiguration" object, but that depends on the nature of what you actually display, whether you have asynchronous tasks running, etc.

Comment: Changing the language causes Phonegap apps to crash on Android, as far as I can tell... so you're in good company.

Comment: @stu.salsbury the problem was actually solved by the approach mentioned in the _edit_ part of my answer, so no crashes anymore to my knowledge.

Comment: @Class Stacker -- thanks, yeah... the issue is that I'm in an HTML5 Phonegap Build environment so your solution is more low-level than I have access to. I'll point my Phonegap issue toward your solution, though.  I think they should implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Put these lines in your Manifest file and see if it works.

```
    <activity
        android:name="youractivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
        android:label="youractivitylabel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of null pointer exceptions in fragments after change locale. For future reference, I share a solution that I found helpful in my case. In the fragment's `onCreateView()` just add this line:

```
this.setRetainInstance(true);
```

This prevents calling `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()`. Instead, `onDetach()` and `onAttach(Activity)` will be called. It helped me, hope it may help others that come to this page.
See [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)).